# Numpy/ arcpy memory issue

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, arcpy

I am doing some raster analysis using numpy and arcpy.
In my script I run a nested for loop creating some numpy arrays which I save as raster at the end of each loop.

At the end of each loop I delete all the arrays

```
del array1, array2
```

and clear the garbage collector

```
gc.collect()
```

However, my memory does not get released and it continues to fill up with each loop. Only if i close the application the memory gets released.

Are their other ways to release memory besides del, and gc.collect()?

Code sample can be found here

https://gist.github.com/thomas-maschler/73e6e75630838e59cdaa#file-gap_fill

Thanks,

Thomas